# How do I recharge my ipad's SIM card?

Tags: ipad, sim

I don't know how SIM cards work in your country, either you should charge (increasing its credit) it every time when its credit is finished Or its credit is unlimited .. anyway my SIM needs to be recharge after a while. Basically I do that like this via the mobile:

- Recharging: `*141*{16 digit code}*1#`
- Seeing the current credit: `*141*1#`

[Based on this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5234914?start=0&tstart=0), that's depends on the sim provide. But actually apple devices are really rare in my country .. So my sim provider doesn't have much information about how to work with ipad.

All I need is to find a **dialer keypad** in the ipad.. is there any? If yes where exactly?

Noted that I'm using [MTN Irancell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTN_Irancell) SIM card. Well can please somebody tell me how can I both *"see current credit"* and *"recharge it"* of the SIM which is into the ipad?

Comment: Doesn't the provider offer a way to recharge a prepaid SIM via a web interface or similar?

Comment: @patrix Yes .. there is a web interface which I can charge my SIM via that. However there is some packages to use internet for the SIM card, I can active them like this `*141*2*1#` .. and it needs a dialer keypad and I cannot do that online by a web interface .. So isn't there any approach to do that?

Comment: Putting the SIM into a phone to charge it would be a way :-)

Comment: That's actually a good question, I struggle with the same thing last week. Along the same line: why doesn't the cellular iPad feature everything like a regular cellphone..?

Comment: @CedricH. Well your question is a good question too `:-)`

Comment: I recharge via my bank, dont know if your banks offer this?

Comment: @emotality Yeah one of my banks supports it. Actually that's a good idea.

Comment: Thats great! :) Should I post it as an answer?

Comment: @emotality Why not `:-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recharge via my online banking, if one of your banks can also offer this, then this would be ideal.